# How to fill a number with a variable amount of 0s?

Tags: c, printf

I'm trying to print a number with a certain amount of zeros before it.
I know that in order to print a constant amount of zeros I need to

> ```
> printf("%05d", num);
> ```

But how can I print a varying amount of zeros? Let's say that the amount will be `int spacing`.

Comment: ..or assemble your format string at runtime, e.g. with sprintf()

Comment: That's not a constant number of zeros, that's a constant field width with *enough zeros to fill the field*.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int alpha = 1;
    int beta = 23456;
    int spacing = 3;

    printf("Alpha: %0*d\n", spacing, alpha);

    spacing = 8;
    printf("Beta:  %0*d\n", spacing, beta);
    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4372KB
Alpha: 001
Beta:  00023456
```